# Determine NetBeans IDE Version in Ant

Tags: netbeans, ant

Within a NetBeans Platform Application build script (build.xml) how would I determine the NetBeans IDE Product Version and Updates information (i.e., the information found in Help-->About)?

[image]

Comment: You do understand that Netbeans is running ANT? If you're lucky Netbeans will set properties. Try running the echoproperties task and look at the output: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echoproperties.html

Comment: Yep, echoproperties let me to exactly what I needed.